# question about viewController and navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So say that I have a table view that has a UINavigationController. On top I have a rightButtonItem that says MAP. Clicking on MAP, will push a MapViewController to the navigationController.

Now on the map I will have a view annotations, clicking on the annotations, I would like to push another view to the navigationController. My question would be, does the map and the table view have the same or separate UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep the same navigation controller through out the application.**YES** All the UIViewControllers make use of the same UINavigationController.

Cheers

Comment: so how do I set a view controller to have a particular UINavigationController... how can I do this? I would like to set the MapViewController to a particular UINavigationController

Comment: Equinox - use [navigationController pushViewController:mapView]` to add the map view to the navigation controller.

Comment: For the first one you usually use initWithRootViewController when creating the navigation controller. For subsequent ones you use UINavigationController's pushViewController method to push the VC onto the stack.

Comment: what's the inverse of pushViewController if I want to go back?

Comment: btw its popViewController...but dude you should refer initial documentation before starting actual coding...

Comment: one more question dude, when you have a navigationController and you push a view.. then on the new view you'll see that back button on top left of the screen.. I want to eliminate this, is such thing even possible?

Comment: yup its definitely possible...Use self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;